# I don't want a line break in the table

Tags: html

In the following code, can I use the width on the left first and break the line only on the right?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bbb</td>
    <td>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the long td to display inline-block/block and give it a width, in order to make that work.

```css
td:nth-of-type(2) {

display: inline-block;
word-wrap: break-word;
width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bbb</td>
    <td>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```